# Инспекция кода, поиски лучших вариантов и баги

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки, инспекция-кода

Надо ли добавлять метку [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), если в вопросе утверждается, что код работает, хотя на самом деле - нет? Пример: [Как найти значение которое повторяется чаще всего?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/793207/178988)

Comment: Думаю, что нет... Если код работает некорректно, да данная метка не должна быть.  Например, я чужой код читаю плохо и если бы Qwertiy не отметил сей факт, я бы и не понял, что код работает неправильно. Хотя если бы потратил на анализ кода несколько часов, может быть и понял, что код не работает как надо.  А данная метка, если бы она присутствовала, сбила бы столку меня, как новичка.

Comment: @Air, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: Qwertiy, сомневаюсь, что понял твой комментарий... Ты спрашиваешь или утверждаешь...? Я сомневаюсь, то мой комментарий сойдет за ответ...

Comment: @Air, я одновременно. Знак вопроса выражает некоторое сомнение и вопрос "почему ты это не в ответы написал?" :)

Comment: Я тя понял...))  Ну все же не смахивает на полноценный ответ....